# flex-grow doesn't display items in container in full width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an ul container and li menu items. Container is 100% width and li items are 50% width of the parent element. Parent is set to display flex and flex direction is column. Now the items are half the width of the flex parents but when I set the child items to `flex-grow: 1` nothing seems to be happening at all.

```
menu-secondary-container ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#menu-secondary li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  line-height: 2.3;
  width: 50% !important;
  padding: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

[image]

I want two items to be in one row and total of two rows.

Comment: because flex-grow will control the height since the direction is column ... so what did you expect the result to be

Comment: you need to use direction row and set `flex-wrap:wrap` and you will get what you want

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I use row and flex-wrap then the li items scretch full width of the container. I need them to be 50% width and two items in each row

Comment: remove the flex-grow and keep only the width

Comment: @TemaniAfif In that case I get everything in one row and scroll bars. Very weird behaviour, tried so many things and nothing works. I could use floats, but they are nasty because when I resize the window, text inside li is breaking and giving me ugly spaces

Comment: `flex-wrap:wrap` should be set to parent and not items

Comment: @TemaniAfif Works great you should I add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above you need to fix your code like this in order to have 2 items per row:

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  line-height: 2.3; 
  flex: 0 1 50%; /* Or flex-basis:50% Or width:50% */
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>bbb</li>
  <li>cccc</li>
  <li>ddd</li>
</ul>
```